# Dragging and dropping div from one position to another position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 rows of Divs:

- div1 div2 div3 div4
- div5 div6 div7 div8
- div9 div10 div11 div12

Does anyone know of a library that allows you to move the divs to the place of another?

For example, if we move div11 to div2 position, I must get in result:

- div1 div11 div2 div3 div4
- div5 div6 div7 div8
- div9 div10 div12

Comment: Are you talking about dragging and dropping a div ? Or simply move it with javascript?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about dragging and dropping a div

Comment: Yes use JQuery UI (draggable, droppable)

Comment: Did you try to search in google how to do it? At least try to use one of the top 3 results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is your friend.

Anyway here is an article with [9 jQuery Drag & Drop Grid Layout Plugins](http://bashooka.com/coding/9-jquery-drag-drop-grid-layout-plugins/)

Answer (score 2):

This could help you.

https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/

Adding a few listeners on the events would help you in placing div11 in front of div2.